# Building in CLion

Tags: clion

Is it possible to build a single file in CLion and see the actual compiler command line being used?

I have a large existing project, which CLion managed to load however it fails to build, I suspect because of various CmakLists.txt setting. However as far as I can tell you can only build an entire project and it gets built using -j 8 so you get a lot of output which does not include the command line being used so it's hard to know what to fix. i know CLion does create a temporary build directory in .clion10 but I was hoping not to have to go a fish around in that.

Also as a newbie to CLion I can't seem to work out how to undock Clion Windows ( on a Windows 7 box ). The "Floating" option doesn't seem to let me drag a Window outside of the main Clion window.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `add_executable` command multiple times.

Here an example :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test_build)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(BUILD_1 main)
set(SOURCE_FILES_1 main.cc)
add_executable(${BUILD_1} ${SOURCE_FILES_1})

set(BUILD_2 main_2)
set(SOURCE_FILES_2 main_2.cc)
add_executable(${BUILD_2} ${SOURCE_FILES_2})
```

**Old anwser :**
You can use `add_subdirectory(path_to_directory)` to use an other CMakeLists and have multiples building process. ie: you have your cmakelists at the root of your project and multiple other in some files of your project. You just use add_subdirectory and you get other build options.

For your other question, on ubuntu i have to split the view and after i can drag in another floating window.

Under you can see one of my projects and the main CMakeLists.txt on the right

[image: Project with multiple CMake]

And the build options on CLion with this structure.

[image: CLion build options]

The CMakeLists.txt under the files are like full project builders.

Comment: you can just do either : `add_executable(foo bar.cc)`

Comment: Having to add_executable for every single file seems insane. Is there any reason why CLIon can't have a "Build" when you right click on a file. If Clion can only build to the granularity of a CMake target that is pretty sad.

Comment: Currently CLion support only CMake, let them time to support other builds methods, instead of passive agressive trollling.