# Move "CmakeList.txt" to another folder in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

```
-project
--main_folder
---files.cpp
--CMakeList.txt
```

I would like to:

```
-project
--main_folder
---files.cpp
---CMakeList.txt
```

But if I move "CMakeList.txt", Clion can not find it in the root of the project.

Is there a way to change the path to search through CMakeList.txt in Clion?

Comment: any reason why "main_folder" isn't the root of your project ?

Comment: @SirDarius What if this project is created by another person, and owned by a whole team. Then it's hard to change location of the build scripts, or if you do, it will be a nightmare to manage version conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiples CMakeLists.txt. And use the `add_subdirectory` command.

Please have a look : [Building in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037970/building-in-clion/29072045#29072045)